# Is Google Search broken for a phrase with quotes?

Tags: google-search

I tried searching Google for a quote as follows:

http://www.google.com/search?q=%22The+condition+affects+more+than+75%25+of+the+population+worldwide%22

As depicted at https://archive.today/vNop8, it would appear that it cannot find the exact quote/phrase, so, it does a phrase-insensitive search, yet the first result is the exact same phrase which it said it couldn't find (I even tried Ctrl+F to make sure, and it all matched the same).

> No results found for "The condition affects more than 75% of the population worldwide".
>
> Results for The condition affects more than 75% of the population worldwide (without quotes):
>
> The condition affects more than 75% of the population worldwide, with ...`

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Thats because **google search does not index some Symbols** like `@` or `%`. Try removing `%` and search with quotes to get matched results.

Read the related article on mashable for more details:

http://mashable.com/2012/01/12/google-twitter-social-search-at-symbol/